# python logging filter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am really confused about this filter thing in logging. I have read the docs and logging cookbook.
I have an application written in several files. Each file has a class and its exceptions.
- main file: mcm
- in mcm I import configurator and initiate its class
- in configurator I import rosApi and initiate its class

What I want to achieve:
- in main file, decide from which modules and its levels I want to log.
- one handler for all. configurable in main file

The idea is that I would like to turn on debugging of given modules on and off in one file, customizable per runtime with option passed to main file.

For example:
If I pass -d it will print (additionally) all debug information from configurator but not rosApi.
If I pass -D it will print all debug from configurator AND rosApi

Comment: You should give examples of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create a logger module, something along these lines:

```
import os
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logfile, maxBytes=10000000, backupCount=10)
fm = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(module)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(fm)
logger.addHandler(fh)
level = os.environ['LOGGING'].upper()
level = getattr(logging, level)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(level)
```

then I do an `import logger` at the top of all my modules.